# composer require reading all version of all package, and take too many time

Tags: composer-php, repository, require

I'm using OroCommerce and want to add a new packge using composer require

Before install my wanted package, composer display message like this

> Reading composer.json of {package_name} ({version})

Composer seems to read all version of all my installed package.
It take so many time to read all version (by example package oroinc/platform have 199 releases)

There is a way to prevent this behavior

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself (in case someone as the same question)
It's no possible https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5943